# cisco: debug command to write a readonly snmp oid?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, cisco-ios

i want to write a readonly snmp oid on a cisco 886va-w to test a network management system called librenms. is there any debug command available for this purpose? the oids belongs to some error counters but there is no error at the moment, so the graphes in librenms doesn't show any activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you constrain yourself to use the real device, you'll have to create the error condition that increments that counter. That is usually hard to do.

Google "mimic simulator" on how to test your app with a simulator that will allow you to create whatever condition you want.